# adc order of conversion in stm32f103 in multichannel conversion

Tags: c, stm32, keil

I am working on adc in stm32f103 controller in keil compiler in this adc, I need perform continuos conversion  up to 6 channels...I need to program the order of conversion in adc1_sqrx. but I didn't found any hint how to program this order of conversion..

Comment: The Stm data sheet doesn't explain how to use the anolog to digital converter pins?

Comment: Have you seen page 75 of St data sheet.

Comment: thank you marshal i just found an answer while going through RM0008
Reference manual in st.com

Answer (score 2):

here in adc1_sqr1 register we need to mention number of conversions required
if you need only one conversion 
0000--- 1 conversion

### **0001--- 2 conversion**

0101--- 6 conversions i need

in adc1_sqr3 sufficient for all 6 conversions that i required
here in 1st conversion i will mention channel number 10
in 2nd conversion -----channel number as 11

### **in 3rd conversion -----channel number as 12**

in 6 th conversion ----channel number as 15

this is nothing but the order of conversion for channel